# Obtaining Coefficients of Powers of polynomial (e.g., $P(x)^N$) for large N, becomes Numerically Unstable

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, computational-complexity, floating-point

**Obtaining Coefficients of Powers of polynomial (e.g., $P(x)^N$) for large N, becomes Numerically Unstable**

I have a polynomial $P(x)$ where $-1\leq P(x) \leq 1$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $-1\leq {\it coefficients} \leq 1$.
I want to find the coefficients of $P(x)^N$ where $N$ is an integer. In Matlab, I use `coeffs(P(x)^N)` to obtain the coefficients of $P(x)^N$. To check the results, I plot `P(x)^N` and also constructed polynomial using the obtained coefficients. However, as $N$ increases, the second polynomial becomes unstable.

**Example**:

```
P= 31/40 - 7/8*x^2 - 9/10*x^4 
[Co,Vo]=coeffs(P^100);

P2=sum((Co).*Vo);
```

`P2` doesn't match the `P^100` and is numerically unstable (e.g. `P2(x)` $\rightarrow \inf$ for some $x \in [-1 1]$)

Does this related to "finite precision computation" of coefficients?

Comment: You could try repeated squaring of $P$, to get $P^2$, $P^4$ and so on, and then write $P^100 = P^{64}P^{32}P^8$, which might lose less precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this effect already with the simpler polynomial 
$$
(1-x)^N=\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}{k}(-x)^k
$$
For $x\approx1$ the left side is very close to $0$. Evaluating the right side involves very large coefficients that have to cancel. The largest is the central one, 
$$
\binom{N}{\lfloor N/2\rfloor}\approx\frac{\sqrt{2\pi N}(N/e)^N}{\pi N(N/(2e))^N}=\frac{2^N}{\sqrt{\pi N/2}}.
$$
As $2^{100}\sim 10^{30}$ one can expect a floating point error of size coefficient times machine epsilon, $\binom{100}{50}\epsilon\sim 2^{100-8/2-52}=2^{44}\sim 1.7\cdot 10^{13}$. Doing the actual numerical computation confirms this scale of the error.